# How to use uiTableFilter for gridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to use uiTableFilter jQuery Plugin  for filter Asp.net gridView

please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I believe the jQuery plugin you refer to requires the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements on your `<table>`, which the asp.net gridview won't give you out of the box.

To add thead and tbody, you could review at least these two articles. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Nov/18/Adding-proper-THEAD-sections-to-a-GridView  - and -   http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/09/add-tbody-and-thead-to-gridview.html

Next, as the plugin is client side, you're going to want to return all records in your gridview and turn-off the gridview's paging. If your table is huge, that won't be very practical.